# Обработка форм PHP

Tags: php, форма

Допустим, есть форма из 20 полей. Какие-то поля обязательны для заполнения, а какие-то нет. Так вот, как мне грамотно обработать форму, проверить заполненность полей, чтобы избежать 20 инициализаций переменных. Например,

```
$a = !empty($_POST['a']) ? $_POST['a'] : null;
$a2 = !empty($_POST['a2']) ? $_POST['a2'] : null;
$a3 = !empty($_POST['a3']) ? $_POST['a3'] : null;
```

И так далее. 
Потом нужно загнать всё в базу с PDO

Comment: Посмотрите на валидацию в популярных фреймворках.

Comment: Данную проверку нужно обязательно делать? это необходимо для базы, что бы null был?

Answer (score 10):

```
<?
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$field)
{
if ($field!="") 
{
$$key=$field;
echo "$$key = $field<BR>"; // для проверки
};
};

?>
```

Comment: Если попадется в POST массив, то некоторые серваки скажут ошибку исполнения :)

Comment: Передать на сервер можно теоретически всё что угодно, в том числе вызвать эту страницу с любыми POST данными. Более жёсткую проверку нужно делать далее, всё зависит от конкретики.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас (**PHP 4 >= 4.1.0**, **PHP 5 < 5.4.0**) то можно использовать import_request_variables('p');

> import_request_variables — Импортирует переменные GET/POST/Cookie в глобальную область видимости

**Пример1:**

```
<?php
    import_request_variables('p');
    echo $x1;
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="x1" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Пример2:**

```
<?php
    import_request_variables('p', 'zzz_');
    echo $zzz_x1;
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="x1" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.import-request-variables.php)

Answer (score 0):

Массивом заводи названия переменных, потом проверяй циклом.